# Using SCSS/SASS in Shopify

Tags: sass, shopify

Can't seem to get SCSS working in Shopify.

My CSS file name 'styles.scss.liquid':

```
$turquoise: #35d7db;

#toolbar {
  width: 100%;
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: $turquoise;
}
```

And my HTML in Shopify:

```
{{ 'styles.scss' | asset_url | stylesheet_tag }}

<div id='toolbar'>
    <p>Tools go here</p>
</div>
```

The color is not showing up, not at all sure what the problem is. Appreciate any advice.

Cheers, DB.

Answer (score 4):

It should be `{{ 'styles.scss.css' | asset_url | stylesheet_tag }}`   You need to add  .css too.

Comment: This hasn't fixed the problem. I still haven't been able to figure it out. @MashR.

Comment: Well I tested [here](http://price-match.myshopify.com/collections/all)  and then gave you the solution.

Comment: I appreciate the effort, and I know it's difficult for you to see exactly what is going on with Shopify, but I'm still not having any luck.

Comment: Give me your store url. give me the code that you used to include the scss file. Give me the code that you used inside it. I will again compare.

Comment: @MashR. should be correct. Is your styles.scss.liquid file in your assets folder?

Answer (score 0):

> **Using Liquid in Sass files**
>
> When you compile Sass on Shopify servers,
> you'll create a style.scss.liquid file. Shopify then compiles the
> Liquid first, then the Sass, to create the final CSS file.

Source: [A Beginner's Guide to Sass with Shopify — Part 3](https://www.shopify.com/partners/blog/a-beginners-guide-to-sass-with-shopify-part-3)

Answer (score 0):

Made this work using `site.scss.liquid` file in the `/assets` folder and adding it to the `theme.liquid` file between the head tags: `{{ 'site.scss.css' | asset_url | stylesheet_tag }}`

Documentation found in https://shopify.github.io/slate/docs/styles-with-liquid

> For example, if you were to upload a styles.scss.liquid file, you
> could include it in your theme with the following markup:
>
> ```
> <link type="text/css" href="{{ 'styles.scss.css' | asset_url }}" rel="stylesheet">
> ```